# Azure SQL Database - Slow

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm currently working with SQL Azure and I realize that it is very slow when I used it with Sql Server Management Studio or Visual Studio 2013 Data Tools for design the database. Is there anyone having the same issue? I tried scaling the database to this configuration but it still working slow :

Server Tier : Standard.
Performance level : S2.

Regards,

Rodrigo

Comment: Is your database on a V12 server?

Comment: No, it's on V11. Do you think that's the problem? Thanks

Comment: V12 should help improve your experience in general as it supports [more capabilities](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/) than pre-V12. There are some performance tests of Pre-V12 vs V12 you can find [here](https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/12/17/azure-sql-database-v12-performance-tests-show-significant-performance-increase/). The main reason I asked is that with V12 servers, there are updates for Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. You can find them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027).

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thanks.

Comment: Im using v12, and it is awfully slow. Expanding tables takes like 5 minutes. It is unusable in SSMS. I have a tiny 4meg database.

Comment: Same problem here - connect SSMS2014 to an Azure SQL database and it becomes unusable - UI frequently unresponsive for 15-20 seconds following something like right-clicking a database in Server Explorer, Windows warning me that Management Studio is not responding. No solution yet though :/

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  Super responsive before the upgrade, SSMS has errors after the upgrade so I installed the latest version of SSMS and now the performance is truly awful, this is not performance of SQL on Azure, it is the interaction between it and the server.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this and wanted to see if other's have a better solution.

You don't get this 'slow' behaviour in SQL Management Studio if you use the 'servers' SA account.

Other accounts were getting it.

Solution

```
USE master
GO
CREATE USER usernameYouLogInWith
    FOR LOGIN usernameYouLogInWith
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
```

Solved.

Immediately right clicking in Management Studio as that user account is now 'instant'.

PS, I know you can't use 'use' in SQL Azure, but at least you know to run that on the master database.
Using V12 DB

Comment: I came to realize this is the solution as well.  You need to connect to the master database as a sql admin and give the problem-user access to the master database.  Otherwise that problem-user will have slow connections to ssms (even to databases other than master).

Comment: See my post below.  Microsoft has commented on the problem as well, and acknowledged yours as one of two different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure also supports S3 performance tier which has same DTU as P1 and half the cost of P1. If you experience the performance issues because of load, you can give a shot and of course you can scale down if needed

Comment: I don't think he is saying that the sql queries are slow to execute. The interface in VS or SSMS is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Once I updated to the latest SSMS and client tools all was well again.

Answer (score 1):

MY understanding is that Microsoft has not yet optimized SSMS to work properly with Azure. That means the application makes excessive number of queries at all times and that makes the UI super slow.

Until Microsoft starts resolving this (using 2016 here and yet very slow), I found a free tool that works at a decent speed, and it has a free version that works for my needs.

DBForge Studio Express
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/download.html

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, this also has visual query design on Azure SQL, which SSMS dosn't have... still.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Microsoft explanation of this issue:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-132-delays-connecting-to-azure-sql-database-from/ba-p/1502030

They describe two types of authenticated users.  Ones with instance LOGIN's and ones that have only access to a single database ("contained" database users).

The problem with the slow SSMS connectivity only affects the first type of authentication (instance LOGIN's when they have access to a database but have no rights to the "master" database).  If you are able to switch to "contained" database users then you may avoid the problem altogether.